# Kotlin Coroutines sequential execution

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to create an object which can execute some tasks sequentially in its own thread like it is a queue.

The following sample is just for demonstrating my setup and may be completely wrong.

```
class CoroutinesTest {
    fun a() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            println("a started")
            delay(1000)
            println("a completed")
        }
    }

    fun b() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            println("b started")
            delay(2000)
            println("b completed")
        }
    }

    fun complex() {
        a()
        b()
    }
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val coroutinesTest = CoroutinesTest()

        coroutinesTest.complex()

        delay(10000)
    }
}
```

For now this code prints the following

```
a started
b started
a completed
b completed
```

which means `a` and `b` executed in parallel. Methods `a`, `b` and `complex` can be called from different threads. Of course, the `complex` method should also support this concept. For now, I need a mechanism that allows me to execute only one task at a moment, so I could get the following output:

```
a started
a completed
b started
b completed
```

I did some research and think that `actor` with a `Channel` can do what needed, but `actor` for now is marked as *obsolete* ([issue #87](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/87)). I don't like the idea of using API that is subject to change, so I would like to do the thing in a common way.

Comment: There will be no common way until Kotlin introduces the replacement for `actor`. I'd just use `actor` and adapt to the new API when it comes out. It probably won't be that different. Or you can avoid `actor` and work with a `Channel` directly.

Comment: I agree -- I use actors and it works perfectly for the exact use case that you describe. Plus, you get to encapsulate a state for it (declaring val and vars inside the actor) as a bonus.

Answer (score 26):

**TL;DR** There are a few options for controlling sequential coroutines.

1. Use a `Channel` to make them run one at a time in the order called
2. Use a `Mutex` to make them run one at a time but without a guarantee of order
3. Use a `Flow` (as described in [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332445/9473786) by BigSt) to make them run one at a time in the order called, however make sure that the flow buffer is large enough or jobs can be lost if the number of jobs "in flight" is larger than the buffer size.
4. If the desired sequence is always the same, put the actual work into suspend functions and call the sequence from within the same coroutine scope to make them run one at a time in the order prescribed by the code

### Channel

One way to control execution order is to use a [Channel](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) - where lazily executed coroutine jobs are passed to the channel to be run in sequence. Unlike the Mutex, the Channel guarantees that the jobs are run in the order they are launched.

```kotlin
class CoroutinesTest {

    private val channel = Channel<Job>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED).apply {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            consumeEach { it.join() }
        }
    }

    fun a() {
        channel.trySend(
            GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                println("a started")
                delay(1000)
                println("a completed")
            }
        )
    }

    fun b() {
        channel.trySend(
            GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                println("b started")
                delay(2000)
                println("b completed")
            }
        )
    }

    fun complex() {
        // add two separate jobs to the channel,
        // this will run a, then b
        a()
        b()
    }
}
```

Calling `complex` always produces:

```
a started
a completed
b started
b completed
```

### Mutex

You can keep jobs from running at the same time with a `Mutex` and `withLock` call. The call order is not guaranteed if you make a bunch of calls in short succession. For example:

```
class CoroutinesTest {
    private val lock = Mutex()
    
    fun a() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            lock.withLock {
                println("a started")
                delay(1000)
                println("a completed")
            }
        }
    }

    fun b() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            lock.withLock {
                println("b started")
                delay(2000)
                println("b completed")
            }
        }
    }

    fun complex() {
        a()
        b()
    }
}
```

Calling `complex` can produce:

```
a started
a completed
b started
b completed
```

or:

```
b started
b completed
a started
a completed
```

### Suspend Functions

If you must *always* run `a` then `b` you can make both of them suspend functions and call them from within a single scope (only allowing the `complex` call, not individual `a` and `b` calls). In this case, the `complex` call does guarantee that `a` runs and completes before starting `b`.

```
class CoroutinesTest {
    
    suspend fun aImpl() {
        println("a started")
        delay(1000)
        println("a completed")
    }

    suspend fun bImpl() {
        println("b started")
        delay(2000)
        println("b completed")
    }

    fun complex() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            aImpl()
            bImpl()
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `complex` always produces:

```
a started
a completed
b started
b completed
```

Comment: The first example with `Mutex` doesn't guarantee the order.  `b started` can be printed first.

Comment: Yes, that is true, it only guarantees that only one runs at a time. The channel does guarantee order though.

Comment: Can I kindly ask anyone to explain further why the Mutex doesn't guarantee the order of execution? The documentation says, "This function is fair; suspended callers are resumed in first-in-first-out order", but it seems not the case.

Comment: @GansoDoido It takes time for `GlobalScope.launch` to actually launch the coroutine, and the order there is what is not deterministic. If you call `GlobalScope.launch { a }` then immediately call `GlobalScope.launch { b }` the code in "b" may actually run first, and acquire the mutex lock first.

Comment: Can you describe if we want to have return from our method how to use channel or flow? @TylerV

Comment: @MohammadMirdar In general you can't - have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o/70178210#70178210) for some more details about asynchronous programs (API to a coroutine is similar to the callbacks shown there). For most asynchronous code you have to move away from the idea of returning data from a non-suspend async function. If you have a more specific question, please ask a separate question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but here's a simpler approach anyway.
Change a() to return the Coroutine job:

```
fun a() = GlobalScope.launch {
    println("a started")
    delay(1000)
    println("a completed")
}
```

Then you can invoke a() / b() like this:

```
a().invokeOnCompletion { b() }
```

This way b() won't be triggered before a() terminates.

Alternatively you can use join:

```
fun complex() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        a().join()
        b()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Flow`s are sequential](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flows-are-sequential), using `MutableSharedFlow` it can be achieved like the following:

```
class CoroutinesTest {

    // make sure replay(in case some jobs were emitted before sharedFlow is being collected and could be lost)
    // and extraBufferCapacity are large enough to handle all the jobs. 
    // In case some jobs are lost try to increase either of the values.
    private val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Job>(replay = 2, extraBufferCapacity = 2)

    init {
        sharedFlow.onEach { job ->
            job.join()
        }.launchIn(GlobalScope)
    }

    
    fun a() {
        // emit job to the Flow to execute sequentially
        sharedFlow.tryEmit(
            // using CoroutineStart.LAZY here to start a coroutine when join() is called
            GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                println("a started")
                delay(1000)
                println("a completed")
            }
        )
    }

    fun b() {
        // emit job to the Flow to execute sequentially
        sharedFlow.tryEmit(
            // using CoroutineStart.LAZY here to start a coroutine when join() is called
            GlobalScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                println("b started")
                delay(2000)
                println("b completed")
            }
        )
    }


    fun complex() {
        a()
        b()
    }
}
```

Note: `GlobalScope` is not recommended to use, it violates the principle of [structured concurrency](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/06_StructuredConcurrency).

Comment: This doesn't let you run `a` and `b` individually though. I added `fun runA() { sharedFlow.tryEmit(a()) }` and similar for `runB` and calling those in sequence does not always produce consistent behavior (e.g. `runA() runB() runA() runB() runB() runA()` sometimes misses the first run, sometimes only one A-B sequence runs, sometimes the order changes)

Comment: As for the first statement it makes sense then to launch a coroutine when calling `tryEmit(...)` function.

Comment: Adding a "name" argument to pass in (e.g. `run("1") run("2") run("3") run("4") run("5") run("6")`) using this I often see it only run "5" and "6" - probably related to the flow replay and buffer size. I have tried the flow approach in the past and it seemed to "lose" jobs.

Comment: Right, I guess it loses some items if they are emitted before `sharedFlow` starts to be collected. Increasing `replay` argument should solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, you have to make replay large enough, but if something external is triggering `a` you could still lose jobs if too many are launched in short succession unless there is an unlimited replay option.

Comment: `extraBufferCapacity` can also be increased for such cases.

Comment: It's weird that for such simple case (sequential execution of coroutines) there is no simple solution. The solution without using different additional helper classes like `Flow`s, `Channel`s etc.

Comment: I think the channel is the cleanest solution I've found if you need the order. I tried to get the flow working for awhile but it seemed like a lot of messing with parameters (replay and buffer, adding a delay to make sure it starts collecting before you start emitting) was needed and even then it wasn't watertight.

Comment: As for using `Flow` I think it works correctly, but provided that you set needed values for `replay` and `extraBufferCapacity` parameters.

Comment: Yeah, you just have to know *a priori* how many sequential jobs you want to have "in flight" before you start dropping jobs. Is there any downside (memory) to setting the buffer and replay to absurdly large numbers?

Comment: Multiplied by 2 just in case :). Cant't tell for sure, but of course it takes some memory, I would choose the value for it (according to the needs * 2).

Comment: Maybe worth adding something to the answer about how to pick those numbers and what the values imply in terms of potential lost jobs?

Comment: Hm, I've already added it in the comments to the code.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. Might be easier to spot as text outside of the code block, but that's fine either way.