# Is there a way to guarantee coroutine execution order when using coroutineScope and launch?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockwebserver

I have some code I want to test that uses structured concurrency in Kotlin:

```kotlin
suspend fun logic(): Something = coroutineScope {
    launch { taskOne() }
    launch { taskTwo() }
    launch { taskThree() }
    launch { taskFour() }

    Something(...)
}
```

The tasks perform an HTTP request using a web client.

In my tests I'm using `MockWebServer`:

```kotlin
val server = MockWebServer()

@Test
fun logicTest() {
    server.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(read("one.json")))
    server.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(read("two.json")))
    server.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(read("three.json")))
    server.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(read("four.json")))

    val result = runBlocking { logic() }

    result shouldBe Something(...)
}
```

The problem is sometimes when running all my tests (about 30) the coroutines are called in the "wrong" order, which is fine in prod but for tests it breaks because of the queueing nature of `MockWebServer`. For example sometimes the order is:

```
taskOne()
taskThree()
// next tasks fail because taskThree throws when given the response "two.json"
```

I want to know if there is a way to guarantee coroutine execution order in tests. This shouldn't modify the prod code, as the order is not important except in tests! So can't use `Mutex` or `Channel`.

I tried using `runTest` and `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(1))`. Also tried `runBlocking(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher())`.

A possible workaround is to use `MockWebServer`'s `Dispatcher` but I really want to keep the queuing as it's easier to understand and contains information about the expected flow of requests.

Another possible workaround is to delay the mock server's responses using `MockResponse.throttleBody()`.

Comment: By definition the production code is not ordered, so why would order matter in your tests? It would be best to tweak the test to pass for any order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Coroutines sequential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution)

Comment: @TylerV That allows controlling execution from within the prod code which I can't change.

Comment: @Joffrey Yes that is true, I'm looking for a way to preserve the ergonomics of calling enqueue on MockWebServer, the workarounds to make it order agnostic are pretty ugly.

Comment: IMO it looks much better to use the MockWebServer's dispatcher approach, where you can express your mock responses based on the queried URLs. I don't see why enqueue is even a thing, it makes the tests so brittle. Even if you could ensure the coroutines are ordered, that means swapping 2 asyncs in production code would fail your test, even though it's perfectly fine

Comment: *and contains information about the expected flow of requests* - Isn't this exactly what *doesn't* matter in this test? It's literally the opposite of your requirements. Which would be reason enough to change the approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a DSL to make working with `MockWebServer`'s `Dispatcher` easier.
https://github.com/akhial/mock-server-dsl

```kotlin
val server = MockWebServer()

val dispatcher = mockResponses {
    matchBody("foo") { MockResponse().setResponseCode(201) }
    matchPath("bar") { MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("baz") }
    matchMethod("GET") { MockResponse().setResponseCode(403) }
    matchMethod("POST") { MockResponse().setResponseCode(200) }
}

server.dispatcher = dispatcher
```