# How to use coroutines so blocks of code are not run at the same time

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Lets suppose I have the following code blocks:

```
BlockA - Reads from a file
BlockB - Writes from a file
BlockC - Deletes a file
```

And I want to make sure they are synchronised such that only one Block can run at a time.  Similar to how @synchronized works.

I do not mind if they all run on the same thread, thereby making it a non issue.  My question is how do I do that with coroutines?  If I just:

```
fun onReadClick() = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  blockA()
}
...
fun onSaveClick() = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  blockB()
}
...
fun onDeleteClick() = scope.launch(Dispatches>IO) {
  blockC()
}
```

This doesn't gaurrantee it right?  Because Dispatchers.IO would just be a pool of threads, not the same thread?
Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Coroutines sequential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a [Mutex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/):

```kotlin
private val mutex = Mutex()

fun onReadClick() = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  mutex.withLock {
    blockA()
  }
}

fun onSaveClick() = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  mutex.withLock {
    blockB()
  }
}

fun onDeleteClick() = scope.launch(Dispatches>IO) {
  mutex.withLock {
    blockC()
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes them run one at a time, but it does not guarantee that they run in the same order they are called.

Comment: @TylerV there is some race due to dispatchers.io but kotlin mutex by itself is fair.

Comment: Yes, if you call `onReadClick` and `onSaveClick` one after the other, you are not guaranteed that the first one reaches the mutex first, so you could have blockB run before blockA. If you don't care about the order, the mutex works fine.

Comment: @TylerV Yes, this is correct. If we need a specific execution order, then we probably should use a `Channel`. Question didn't mention this. It asked about synchronized blocks and launching concurrent operations - both of them are unfair, so I didn't even look for a fair solution.

Comment: This can work but we need to ensure mutex locking is not a subject for a parallel race. So we would need to remove IO dispatcher from launch and rely on `scope` being confined to a single thread like Dispatchers.Main or limited parallelism. Only after obtaining mutex we would either switch to IO or we would already be in its context (in case of limitedParallelism).

Comment: @Pawel why do you assume we can't acquire a lock from parallel coroutines? Main point of using a mutex is synchronizing concurrent coroutines. You would like to ensure exclusive access to an util which is mainly designed to provide exclusive access? :⁠-⁠)

Comment: We can but that causes a race issue so at least the acquisition part needs to be confined to ensure block execution order. It would work in practice but from a design standpoint - writing code that relies on mutex lock order to queue tasks is bad.

Comment: @Pawel To be honest, I'm not sure what do you mean. It's at all valid and natural to acquire locks from multiple coroutines in parallel - similarly as we can invoke synchronized methods in Java from multiple threads. This is the main purpose of these tools. If you mean that we don't have guarantees on execution order, then this is true. As said above, it was not requested by the author explicitly and their sample code was already unordered due to using `launch()`. As a matter of fact, my answer is unordered not due to a mutex, which is itself fair, but because of the `launch()`.

Comment: @Pawel Also, I doubt your suggested solution with non-parallel dispatcher actually do any different. Even if using a single thread, we still don't have guarantees on the execution order due to using `launch()`. If we need to guarantee ordering, then I think we should send to a `Channel` or maybe launch in unconfined dispatcher and then lock (but I'm not sure if the latter is correct).

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone.  I still digesting the discussion between broot and @Pawel and am not totally sure what to make of it.  In particular, I'm not sure sure about the comment that suspend points will yeild to one another.  That doesn't seem to be what I am looking for and mutex seems a better bet?  Or at least one I can guarantee regardless of the code inside?  Honestly I'm still not sure.

Comment: @SpecialEd you probably want mutex. However to keep inner block order execution from being jumbled (ie. after calling onRead onSave in quick succession you get blockB before blockA) you have to be mindful about when you obtain the lock. Ideally you'll want to do it on main or single thread dispatcher before switching to IO to do heavy file operations.

Comment: @Pawel Okay that makes sense.  I'm not really concerned about order actually.  The example was simplified from the real code, but we dont need to worry about order.  Anyway, thanks everyoone for their input, I did learn more about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dispatcher that provides parallelism guarantee with [`limitedParallelism`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/limited-parallelism.html):

```kotlin
val fileDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1)

fun onReadClick() = scope.launch(fileDispatcher) {
  blockA()
}
// etc.
```

If your use case allows it you can even include it as default dispatcher of your `scope`:

```kotlin
val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1))

fun onReadClick() = scope.launch {
  blockA()
}
// etc.
```

Be aware of caveats that come with altered dispatcher - if your blocks are not strictly blocking and include suspending points they will yield execution between each other. To avoid it you would still want to nest a `Mutex.withLock` in there:

```
fun onReadClick() = scope.launch { mutex.withLock { blockA() } }
```